# Why is git flow feature checkout being deprecated? What should I be using instead?

Tags: git, deprecated, git-flow

I'm running `git` version `2.3.6` and `git flow` version `1.8.0` and when I run commands like `git flow feature checkout <branch>` I get the message:

```
The command 'git flow feature checkout/co' will be deprecated per version 2.0.0
```

Does anyone know why this would be deprecated and/or what I should be using instead?

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure which exact `git flow` command line utility it is. If it helps I'm running `Ubuntu 15.04` and installed it using `aptitude install git-flow` which is reported as version `1.8.0-1` by aptitude and running `git flow version` prints `1.8.0 (AVH Edition)`. I don't believe I've added a `git flow` specific PPA or anything, so I'm guessing it's available in the standard Ubuntu packages. Based on 'AVH Edition', it looks like it's this: https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the version number specified in your question (1.8.0), you are referring to https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow (as opposed to https://github.com/nvie/gitflow, whose most recent release, at the time of writing this answer, is 0.4.1). After cloning that repo and inspecting its log, by running

```
git log --grep=feature --grep=deprecated --all-match
```

I only found [one relevant commit](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow/commit/313512437d56940580a76c8d0546fb0c717f72b7), which doesn't motivate the deprecation of `git flow feature checkout`.

However, [issue #128](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow/issues/128) in the repo's issue tracker on GitHub contains a discussion about the planned deprecation of `git flow feature checkout`. Here is a relevant passage of a comment by the maintainer:

> ## My thoughts
>
> ### Checkout
>
> - With bash/zsh completion this command seems irrelevant but if you
>   don't use completion it could be helpful.
> - I suggest dropping this command in a future release and add a
>   warning per v1.8.0 that the command will be dropped on a future
>   version (2.0?)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks a lot. I guess the preference is just to use `git checkout <prefix>/<branch>` manually then. I was only really planning to use it for an alias as a short form where I didn't have to enter the prefix. I can always work around that with a more complex alias.

Comment: @Thor84no I don't use gitflow, but my understanding is that you can use `git flow feature checkout` and `git checkout` (without flags) interchangeably.

Comment: More or less. The advantage of `git flow feature checkout` is that you don't have to include the branch prefix (usually `feature/`, but not exclusively). It's still pretty similar, but when making an alias for a short form like `git cof JIRA-123` it means the difference between just forwarding to `git flow feature checkout` and writing a small shell script that handles parameters and adds the prefix (`feature/`) on to the branch name.

Comment: @Thor84no Should be no problem.